# WebBrowser starts rendering at small size

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am currently creating a WebBrowser as follows;

```
WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser.Height = 400;
webBrowser.Width = 600;
```

And adding it to my canvas;

```
currentCanvas.Children.Add(webBrowser);
```

But I have the problem that it starts rendering at a smaller size than it will eventually be.

When it starts rendering;

[image]

And when it is done rendering;

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get the WebBrowser to start at the size it should be when it is done rendering (full size)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by moving the viewport meta-tag to the top of the `<head>` tag

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```